# Microsoft store says: where do you want to install? It looks like you don't have any applicable device(s)

Tags: microsoft-store

All I wanted to do was install the new Windows Terminal, but I opened the store and tried to install it when my mouse hovered over the install button and turned into a circle-with-slash-through icon.

Next to the install button is a "...", but when I open "Install on my devices" I get a message that says: "Where do you want to install? It looks like you don't have any applicable device(s) linked to your Microsoft account. To install, sign in on a device with your microsoft account"

I signed in with my account on this computer, but the message is the same.

How can I install programs like Windows Terminal with the Microsoft Store? I can install Solitaire through the Microsoft Store.

[image]

I have verified that over here on the account.microsoft.com/devices/content page that I can see the device I want to install programs onto.

[image]

Comment: Are you logged into your Microsoft Account within the Microsoft Store UWP application?  Likewise, while your device might have been linked to your Microsoft Account, it certainly is possible that isn't the case currently.  What I can confirm is the option to unlink the device should exist, based on your screenshot, that isn't the case.  You should also verify the requirements for Windows Terminal is being meet.

Comment: @Ramhound First, I cropped the image to remove the "Unlink" link on the right, which was to save space. And, second, how do I verify the requirements? I didn't see requirements. Am I looking in the wrong place? (Hint: I probably didn't see there requirements at the bottom saying that I need to update windows... more on this soon)

Comment: The [requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab) to install Windows Terminal is indicated on the page for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the software requirements by expanding the tab at the bottom of the Store interface. There is a required update before installing Windows Terminal, and the update is linked in the software requirements section. The link takes you to a Microsoft download page where you can find a program to install the update automatically. After windows is updated and rebooted, come back to the Store and the Windows Terminal application has all the software requirements met, and you have the ability to click the install button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to log into the Microsoft Store with your own Account, or if this is a business computer, your business will have or can have a business account.

I use a Microsoft Account with my computer here and installation of the new Terminal was straightforward.

If for some reason, the Company cannot accommodate you, then you can continue to use the Command Prompt and PowerShell.

Also make sure UAC (User Account Control) is enabled, and are a modern version of Windows 10 (V1909 or beyond).

Comment: You need to ask the Company IT Administrrator

Comment: You can continue to run Command and PowerShell. Both still work..  I added this to my response.

Comment: I am the administrator

Comment: the goal is to launch windows terminal, not cmd and not powershell.